# How to use custom widgets in django forms (datetime picker)

Tags: jquery, python, django, datetime

I'm trying to implement a datetime picker in a django form, I've also tried to find a jQuery picker but none fitted me, so I got back to trying with Django forms. After looking for days for a solution I've been checking custom widgets and found one:

class TimeW(widgets.MultiWidget):

{...etc...}

But now, I don't know how to use it, I tried this:

```
lastcheck = forms.DateField(forms.TimeW())
```

But it gives me a:

> AttributeError at /
>
> 'module' object has no attribute 'TimeW'

Answer (score 0):

You get the attribute error because you are using `forms.TimeW`, but `TimeW` is not defined in `forms`.

Change your field to:

```
lastcheck = forms.DateField(widget=TimeW())
```

If `TimeW` is defined in the same module, that will work. If `TimeW` is defined somewhere else, you'll have to add the import to the top of the module.

```
from path.to.widget import TimeW
```

Comment: It is, it's in forms.py, same as the form I want to use

Comment: In that case, changing the code to `widget=TimeW()` should fix the attribute error.